# SQL Using more than one result using WITH Clause

Tags: t-sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why can’t I access my CTE after I used it once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590994/why-cant-i-access-my-cte-after-i-used-it-once)

How can I get more than one result using WITH ?

```
;WITH X AS
    (SELECT whatever)

, Y AS
    (SELECT whatever FROM X)

SELECT * FROM Y WHERE condition

SELECT Count(*) FROM X                <==== X doesn't work here
```

I don't want **@@RecordCount**, this counts **Y**, not **X**

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the CTE after the statement it's a part of has completed.

You could include it in your first resultset, though:

```
SELECT Y.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X) as X_Count
FROM Y
WHERE condition
```

but, that would include that value in each row of the result.

You're probably better off making X a table variable rather than a CTE.