# Create string with some parent child data and match it with a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables given below :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
  (
     id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
     parent1 INT,
     parent2 INT,
     RKey    VARCHAR(max)
  )

CREATE TABLE table2
  (
     id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
     RKey VARCHAR(max)
  )
```

Relationship between these two table is table1.parent2 = table2.id. Table1.parent1 is used to maintain recursive relationship and the table1.RKey is calculated as shown in this image:
[image: Example hierarchy]
but, There are some record with wrong RKey, see below is some sample data :

```
insert into table1 (id,parent1,parent2,RKey) 
values
--hierarchy 1
(5010,NULL,1004,'1002.1004.5010'),              --level 1
(5011,5010,1004,'1002.1004.5010.5011'),         --level 2
(5012,5010,1004,'1002.1004.5010.5012'),         --level 2
--hierarchy 2
(5020,NULL,1005,'1002.1005.5020'),              --level 1
(5021,5020,1005,'1002.1005.5020.5021'),         --level 2
(5022,5021,1005,'1002.1005.5020.5021.5022'),    --level 3
(5023,5021,1005,'1002.1005.5020.5021.5023'),    --level 3
--hierarchy 3
(5030,NULL,1004,'1002.1004.5030'),              --level 1
(5031,5030,1004,'1002.1004.50301.5031'),        --level 2
(5032,5030,1004,'1002.1004.50301.5032'),        --level 2
--hierarchy 4
(5040,NULL,1004,'1002.1004.50401'),             --level 1
(5041,5040,1004,'1002.1004.50401.50411'),       --level 2
(5042,5041,1004,'1002.1004.50401.50411.5042'),  --level 3
(5043,5041,1004,'1002.1004.50401.50411.5043')   --level 3

--parent2 will be same in a hierarchy.

insert into table2 (id,RKey) 
values
(1004,'1002.1004'),
(1005,'1002.1005')
```

RKey in hierarchy 1 and 2 are correct but if you see hierarchy 3 and 4, the RKey is wrong. now, I want to return such record with query/queries which have incorrect Rkey with an additional column showing correct Rkey. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f16bd/14) is an SQL Fiddle with sample data and what I have tried till now.

Expected Result :

```
id      WrongRKey                           CorrectRKry
----    ----                                ----                    
5031    1002.1004.50301.5031                1002.1004.5030.5031     
5032    1002.1004.50301.5032                1002.1004.5030.5032     
5040    1002.1004.50401                     1002.1004.5040          
5041    1002.1004.50401.50411               1002.1004.5040.5041     
5042    1002.1004.50401.50411.5042          1002.1004.5040.5041.5042
5043    1002.1004.50401.50411.5043          1002.1004.5040.5041.5043
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joins are incorrect.

Below a corrected sql statement with CTE, also I have included a **update join** statement, remember that CTE are only "one shot", [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590994/why-cant-i-access-my-cte-after-i-used-it-once)

Here a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f16bd/15)

```
with cte (Id, WrongRKey, CorrectRKey)
as
(
select    
       b.id
      ,b.RKey 
      ,c.RKey + '.' +
      case when a.parent1 is null then '' else cast(a.parent1 as varchar) + '.' end +
      case when b.parent1 is null then '' else cast(b.parent1 as varchar) + '.' end +
      case when b.id is null then '' else cast(b.id as varchar)  end 
from table1 a 
        right join table1 b
     on a.id = b.parent1
        inner join table2 c
     on a.parent2 = c.id or b.parent2 = c.id
)

--update
--  tb1
--SET RKEY = ct.CorrectRKey
--from 
--    table1 tb1 
--      inner join cte ct 
--  on tb1.id = ct.id


select *
from cte 
where WrongRKey <> CorrectRKey
```

Also my advice is to use a build-in data type called hierarchy id here the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx) for this type data.

Comment: I also have tried by comparing RKEY <> COMPUTEDRK1 but the problem in this is, if Rkey on parent itself is incorrect then it wont work. for e.g. in you sql fiddle, it is returning 5041 record but why it did not return 5042 and 5043 as those are also incorrect. rkey for 5040 is computed in upper query so rkey for 5041 should be '1002.1004.5040.5041', rkey for 5042 should be '1002.1004.5040.5041.5042' ansd so on... by the way thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve: 1) try to explain COMPUTEDRK1 and COMPUTEDRK2 2) Explain `if parent1 is not null then table2.rkey + (table1.id of all the parent in sequence) + table1.id` **all the parent in sequence** 3) I think is wrong the COMPUTEDRK1 and RK2 calculated fields because the query is correct. (by the way you r welcome)

Comment: Ok recap: RKey for some records is wrong and you want to recalculate the RKey based on rules on pic and getting the wrong recs but this only for 2nd formula, is correct ?

Comment: I have listed this only 3 levels but in actual data this can vary from 2 to 10. and above solution will only work till level 3. so I think need to self-join table1 9 times. I have around 1M rows in table1 and 37 in table2. let me try this one..

Comment: The problem is the DB design, for this type of problem is better to use HierarchyId data type...

Comment: yeah I accept... but I am not authorized to change the design.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another method with `CTE` and I think it is better than joining same tables multiple times :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT id,
                parent1,
                parent2,
                RKey,
                Cast(id AS VARCHAR(300)) AS ComputedRKey
         FROM   table1
         WHERE  parent1 IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT p.id,
                p.parent1,
                c.parent2,
                p.RKey,
                Cast(c.ComputedRKey + '.'
                     + Cast(p.id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS VARCHAR(300)) AS ComputedRKey
         FROM   table1 p
                JOIN cte c
                  ON p.parent1 = c.id)
SELECT c.id,
       c.RKey                            AS WrongKey,
       ( p.RKey + '.' + c.ComputedRKey ) AS CorrectRKey
FROM   cte c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 p WITH(nolock)
                    ON c.parent2 = p.id 
WHERE  c.RKey <> ( p.RKey + '.' + c.ComputedRKey )
```