# WITH-AS statement with declare and set

Tags: sql-server

I'm a newbie of sql-server and I've been learning sql queries about with-as and declare and set.

I have a question to make my query short.

```
DECLARE @MaxID int;
SET @MaxID = (SELECT MAX(rowNumber) FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NoWkOrd ASC) AS rowNumber, a, b FROM 
t
) t1) ;
SELECT rowNumber, NoWkOrd, CdEquip, DtWkOrd
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NoWkOrd ASC) AS rowNumber, a, b
   FROM t
 ) t1
WHERE rowNumber > @MaxID
```

This is an orignal query and I want to make this short by using with-as cuz two query inside of from is used twice at the same time.

```
DECLARE @MaxID int;
WITH t1
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NoWkOrd ASC) AS rowNumber, a, b
FROM t
)
SET @MaxID = (SELECT MAX(rowNumber) FROM (t1) ;
SELECT rowNumber, NoWkOrd, CdEquip, DtWkOrd
FROM t1
WHERE rowNumber > @MaxID
```

But here's an error around SET but i'm still struggling with what is wrong...

Comment: look at link below. You are using your CTE (that's what you are calling with-as). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590994/why-cant-i-access-my-cte-after-i-used-it-once

Comment: When assigning a variable from tables, CTEs, etc, use `SELECT` instead of `SET`. e.g. `SELECT @MaxID = MAX(rowNumber) FROM t1;`. You can't use `SET` with a CTE like that.

Comment: You can't define a CTE and both select a result from it and assign to a variable. You probably don't need to anyway, what are you actually trying to do? Even if your code was valid it would return 0 rows. No row in t1 can have a row number greater than the max row number in t1.

Comment: @AB_87 Thank you for letting me know that concept.

Comment: @ZLK Tbh, I don't get what you are talking about... I don't resolve my problem yet.

Comment: The keyword `SET` cannot be used like you're currently using it (with the `WITH` statement, aka a CTE). You _MUST_ use `SELECT` (or update/delete/insert) after a CTE. So to assign the variable you would do something like `WITH t1 AS (...) SELECT @MaxID = MAX(rowNumber) FROM t1;` Then do whatever with it. But as Martin points out, even if you assign the variable, the next statement is meaningless...